# Styling based on attr on Styled components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am working with `details` and `summary` tags in React using styled-components, I want to be able to style the summary tag based on if the details is open or not using the details attribute boolean flag.

```
<Details open>
  <summary>Epcot Center</summary>
  <p>Epcot is a theme park at Walt Disney World Resort featuring exciting attractions, international pavilions.</p>
</Details>
```

Please how do I achieve this CSS markup below in styled-components?

```
details[open] > summary {
color: red
}
```

I tried this and it did not work, please help

```
const Details = styled.details`
  [open] > summary {
    color: white;
    background: tomato;
  }
`;
```

Comment: Will this help [attribute = value] {   css declarations; }? ;let me check if custom attribute helps

Comment: `:not([open]` & `[open]` works, have posted one sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to render `<Details open />` and not `<details open />`. And, in `<Details />` definition:

```
const Details = styled.details`
  ${({ open }) => open && css`
    & > summary {
      color: white;
      background: tomato;
  }
`}`;
```

P.S.: `css` is an import from `styled-components` too:

`import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'`

Comment: Thank you for your solution works, I rendered the component as `<Details open />`, I will edit my question to reflect this.
I never thought of using the open as a prop and yes, I do use the `css` from styled-components

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```css
.my-details:not([open]) { height: 1.25em; color:red}
.my-details[open] { height: 3.75em; color:green}
```

```html
<details class="my-details" open="open">
  <summary>Epcot Center</summary>
  <p>Epcot is a theme park at Walt Disney World Resort featuring exciting attractions, international pavilions.</p>
</details>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for plain css, I was asking about react styled-components.